# Blank Parameter to Null Parameter in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a drilldown report whose parameters are: parent report - @valid Nvarchar(20) = '' and in child report - @valid Nvarchar(20) = Null.

Both reports run very well but I have an issue after mapping up this parameters in the Text Box Properties > Action > Go to Report. When the report is run I get the error,

"the value provided for the report parameter is not valid"

The query for this report is from a stored Procedure. In the child report, Parameter Properties, I have ticked the "allow Null values" text box, Set available parameter to come from a query and specify a default value to come from a query. What have I done wrong to allow for the error returned? Your help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that this is what you're after, but you can pass an expression like `=IIf(Parameters!valid.Value = "", Nothing, Parameters!valid.Value)` to the child report parameter, i.e. NULLing out empty strings. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Oh, cool! It was just a guess, so I just added a comment, but since it seems on the mark I will add as a proper answer in a few seconds... Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're second report is expecting a NULL values, (i.e. `Nothing` in SSRS), you can pass an expression-based parameter to the child report based on the parent parameter, making sure that if it's an empty string at the parent level, you can explicitly set this to Nothing:

```
=IIf(Parameters!valid.Value = "", Nothing, Parameters!valid.Value)
```

This way the empty string will never get passed and your child report; only the NULL value it expects.

Answer (score 2):

if you're considering passing a null parameter from URL, let's say some sort of CLI, you must include a **parameter:isNull=True** in the parameter section of the URL. and allways remenber to check the "allow null value" in report editor, parameter properties.

let's say we have a report, of sports and stadiums, and we have a null sport... it would be something like this>

```
http://<server/report>&rs:Command=Render&rc:Parameters=false&rc:toolbar=false&sport:isNull=True&stadium=CampNou
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the Parameter to `Allow Blank = Yes` and the `Default Value = ""`.  In the code make allowances for the blank parameter.

Comment: Maybe you can format your answer better readable with code pieces instead of unformated inline code?